# Configure business activity monitor with API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am setting up WSO2 API Manager with Business Activity Monitor.  I follow the steps in the link below & have started BAM successfully.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

However, when I go to "Configure WSO2 API Manager" I see an error trying to go to the the "Configure Analytics" tab (logs below).

Exact same scenario as this defect, but can't find any other tips on the web on how to resolve.  Thanks in advance!
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3765

```
2015-11-17 22:47:15,414 org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "enableAnalytics" from undefined (/admin-dashboard/site/themes/default/templates/analytics-task/template.jag#551) More
TID[-1234] [AM] [2015-11-17 22:47:15,414] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} - org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "enableAnalytics" from undefined (/admin-dashboard/site/themes/default/templates/analytics-task/template.jag#551) org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571) org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273) org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:541) org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
2015-11-17 22:47:15,384 Error occurred while retrieving Datasource configurations (Cause:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.)  More
TID[-1234] [AM] [2015-11-17 22:47:15,384] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.analytics.list:jag} - Error occurred while retrieving Datasource configurations (Cause:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.) 
2015-11-17 22:47:15,377 Illegal access attempt at [2015-11-17 22:47:15,0376] from IP address 172.17.0.3 while trying to authenticate access to service NDataSourceAdmin More
TID[-1234] [AM] [2015-11-17 22:47:15,377] WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} - Illegal access attempt at [2015-11-17 22:47:15,0376] from IP address 172.17.0.3 while trying to authenticate access to service NDataSourceAdmin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around provided in [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3765) in your question. you can check that.

below is the extracted answer in jira.

you have to update the user-mgt.xml as well if you changed the admin password from management console. just change the admin password in user-mgt.xml also.